# Are there any other purposes for variables in math other than functions?

Tags: calculus, limits

I was taught at some point that if you divide variables by each other it works as a form of subtraction. For example: $xy/x=y$, because $x/x = 1$. Today I was told however that you can never divide by a variable in a function unless its a limit or you know the variable is not zero because it could be a root.

If this is so, then what is the of the rule of dividing variables for in the first place?

Comment: You make no sense.

Comment: The problem is that someone **taught** him nonsense like "you can never divide by a variable in a function unless its a limit".

Comment: @Lucian: I'm tempted to flag your comment as offensive. That's not a very helpful thing to say when someone has come here with a genuine question.

Comment: Not sure why this question got downvoted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable is just a name for some mathematical object. In your case, it is usually a name or placeholder for a number. If you don't know the number, you may perform only operations that are allowed for any number. So as we are not allowed to write $\frac 10$ or $\sqrt{-1}$ (before we learned about complex numbers), we are in general not allowed to write $\frac1x$ or $\sqrt x$, because it *might* happen that $x=0$ in the first expression or $x<0$ in the second expression.

That being said, if we *know* by some condition that $x\ne 0$ / $x\ge 0$ then we *may* write these expressions. Otherwise one should always add a cautionary phrase such as "$y=\frac 1x+\sqrt{x+7}$ provided $x\ne 0$ and $x\ge-7$". 
Likewise if you feel the urge to divide by a variable or an expression involving variables, you should start a case distinction: Treat one case where the expression is nonzero the way you were just about to do, i.e. divide by it and see what gives; treat a second case where the expression is zero, which may require totally different approaches: To solve $x(x+1)=2x^2$, you want to divide both sides by $x$. So to be precise you continue "If $x\ne 0$ we can divide both sides by $x$ and obtain $x+1=2x$, hence $x=1$ is a solution." You must not forget the alternative case: "If on the other hand $x=0$, the equation becomes $0\cdot 1=2\cdot 0^2$, which is true, hence we have another solution $x=0$." See that without this extra carefulness you would have missed 50% of the solutions?

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean Hagan. Thanks a lot! Very helpful

Answer (score 1):

The problem: you can't divide by zero! Variables are placeholders, can take different values. If you **know** that $x\ne 0$ (**why** is another question), you can divide by $x$.

Answer (score 1):

You do in fact have to know that $x\neq 0$ in either case, so that part isn't new. I have no idea why someone said that you can't divide by a variable in a function unless it's a limit. This is one way to handle the division by zero case though: rather than directly dividing by zero, which can generate contradictions, you divide by numbers closer and closer to zero and see what happens as you get near it. This lets you figure out what's going on there while staying logically safe.

So the rule is (and has always been, though they might not have said the last bit) : "No dividing by zero, ever. *But*, if that does happen somewhere, you can still learn useful information by probing it with limits instead".

Comment: "I have no idea why someone said that you can't divide by a variable in a function unless it's a limit." Because some teachers are *very* lousy.

Comment: He said that each variable x is a root on the graph, so by dividing the expression by variable x it would thereby be dismantling the equation. He said to multiply or divide by constants but not variables.

It didn't really make sense to me, hence, why I came on here to ask. Does this make any sense to you mate? Thanks

Comment: @tazheneryduck0 No, that doesn't make any sense. If you divide by $x$ you need to know that any results you get are only okay if $x\neq 0$, because otherwise the division wasn't allowed. But you can definitely divide by variables to find solutions to equations, it's used all the time. Your teacher seems to be confused. If $x$ is a root then $f(x)$ is what ends up being zero. That doesn't prevent you from dividing by $x$ at all.